Unable to clone repository on WSL 2 Ubuntu
So, currently I'm trying to setup 2 SSH keys, one for the company GitLab and one for my personal GitHub. For context, I followed this steps and this is my current /.ssh/config file:
# Company account
    Host gitlab.company.com
    HostName gitlab.company.com
    User my_user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_company
    IdentitiesOnly yes

# Github account
    Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User my_user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Also, these are the files created at /.ssh/:  id_rsa_company, id_rsa_personal, id_rsa_company.pub, id_rsa_personal.pub
If I run ssh -T git@github.com, the message displayed is Hi {my_github_user}! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.. For my understanding, the setup worked.
The problem is, when i run git clone git@github.com:my_github_user/repository_name.git it gets stuck like this and no progress is made after long minutes waiting:
remote: Enumerating objects: 59, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (59/59), done.
remote: Compressing objects:   3% (2/54)

I have tried to clone the GitHub repository with the new SSH key and the command gets stuck with no response. Tried cloning with HTTPS and didn't work too.
Any ideas of what could be happening on my case?

How big is the repo you're trying to clone?

Also: you don't have to set up separate keys for separate services. That's only necessary when you're trying to use multiple discrete accounts on the same service from the same system (e.g. if you're using a work-related account and also a personal account on the same system and both need to talk to GitHub).

"remote: Compressing objects:   3% (2/54)" You've successfully connected to the repository and it's being cloned. So everything related to SSH keys is no longer interesting — your SSH connection works. The problem is the repo is large. Try to clone it in small batches. Start with git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:my_github_user/repository_name.git

Thanks for the comments. The repo is actually pretty small (less than 1MB), and trying to clone with --depth=1 ended on the same result -> stuck on Counting or Compressing objects.
